# Mouse sensitivity ratcheting downwards

Tags: windows-10, drivers, mouse

Every time I run a particular application (a ~20 year old one, which changes the screen resolution) my mouse sensitivity is lower after I exit (and screen resolution goes back to normal).

At first, I just went to "Mouse Settings -> Cursor Speed" and increased it, but every time I ran the application I had to increase it more and more afterwards. I'm now at the limit of mouse sensitivity, and cannot increase it any further. The mouse is slower than ever.

I've even doubled mouse speed using Regedit, but after using the application a few more times even that's not enough! I've also tried removing the driver and reinstalling it, to no avail. I've tried multiple different mouses/mice, and that doesn't seem to be the problem.

I now seem to be stuck with a slow pointer, "maximum" cursor speed setting, and seemingly no way to make this better.

**How can I fix this??**

(I want to reverse this problem, rather than just go into Regedit and find a hacky way of increasing sensitivity further beyond 2x. I'm using Windows 10.)

Comment: Does a reboot resolve the problem?

Comment: Unfortunately no, this started a while ago and I've done many reboots since.

Comment: If you have enabled System Restore, you could rollback to before you ran this app.

Comment: ... Or perhaps find the mouse in Device Manager, delete the device and reboot using the keyboard or power button, so it gets reinitialized.

Comment: No dice... Problem remains.

Comment: I understand System Restore is a no go (a pity). If that app has an installer, try to uninstall it using [Revo Uninstaller Freeware](https://www.revouninstaller.com/revo-uninstaller-free-download/).

Answer (score 0):

First, check if you have another control panel for mouse behavior. For example, Synaptics adds additional tabs to the *Additional mouse options*. This might have settings that override the main Windows CPL.

[image: Additional Mouse CPL]

Also, a third-party app that sets mouse sensitivity might work, such as free [Custom Mouse Curve](https://esreality.com/post/2363191/custom-mouse-accel-program-for-windows/). Set *Enhance pointer precision" *ON* in the Windows CPL for this to work, and log off and then on again for the new settings to take effect.